# What does [webView loadRequest:[webView request]] do?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I was assuming that it would refresh the page but I have hidden parameters within the page and after `[webView  loadRequest:[webView request]]` these parameters are retained (which is not the case when I refresh the page on Safari; it resets everything to default).

EDIT: `[webView loadRequest:[webView request]]` behaves differently than `[webView reload]`. I had an alert with a cancel button on it. When I set Cancel to `reload`, it reloads the page over and over again. However, `loadRequest:` reloads the page only once.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `UIWebView`s `-reload` if you want to reload the page?

Comment: I actually don't want to refresh the page. `[webView loadRequest:[webView request]]` behaves differently than `[webView reload]`. I just don't understand why.